# Limit SQL result by type (column value)

Tags: sql, limit

I have a table DailyMeal:

```
Name     | Type
------------------------
orange   | fruit
carrot   | vegetable
apple    | fruit
potato   | vegetable
eggplant | vegetable
cucumber | vegetable
lemon    | fruit
```

My query should return all vegetables and one and only one fruit, doesn't matter which one.

Is it possible with single query? No stored procedure.

Edit: Yes union it is. Thanks all posters.

Comment: You should always state the DBMS and if possible the version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select * from daily_meal where type = 'fruit' limit 1
union
select * from daily_meal where type = 'vegetable'
```

example

```
mysql> desc daily_meal;
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| name  | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| type  | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from daily_meal;
+----------+-----------+
| name     | type      |
+----------+-----------+
| apple    | fruit     |
| potato   | vegetable |
| eggplant | vegetable |
| cucumber | vegetable |
| lemon    | fruit     |
| orange   | fruit     |
| carrot   | vegetable |
+----------+-----------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from daily_meal where type = 'fruit' limit 1
    -> union
    -> select * from daily_meal where type = 'vegetable';
+----------+-----------+
| name     | type      |
+----------+-----------+
| apple    | fruit     |
| potato   | vegetable |
| eggplant | vegetable |
| cucumber | vegetable |
| carrot   | vegetable |
+----------+-----------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but the way you wrote it returns LIMIT 1 against the entire UNION-ed set

Comment: Yep, The second query needs to be an inline view for it to work

Comment: @Richard aka cyberkiwi: According to the MySQL docs, `limit` (or even `order by`) applies only to part of the union. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

Comment: @Andomar try this yourself - `select 1 union all select 2 limit 1;`  I see 1 record. I'm itching to downvote this answer but I'll wait for it to be fixed or deleted. FWIW, you should use **`UNION ALL`** anyway.

Comment: @ Richard aka cyberkiwi: Just tested, and the lower limit affects the entire union.  The MySQL documentation says "To use an ORDER BY or LIMIT clause to sort or limit the entire UNION result, parenthesize the individual SELECT statements and place the ORDER BY or LIMIT after the last one.", which seems to contradict how it really works :)

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from DailyMeal where Type = 'vegetable' or Name = 'orange'
```

or

```
select * from DailyMeal where Type = 'vegetable' or Name in (select top 1 Name from DailyMeal where Type = 'fruit')
```

Comment: Added second example using subquery.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
SELECT * FROM DailyMeal WHERE Type = 'vegetable'
UNION Select TOP 1 * FROM DailyMeal WHERE Type = 'fruit'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could achieve this using a UNION - to join together all those with a type of vegetables, and a separate query that limts 1 of fruit.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM DailyMeal
 WHERE type = 'vegetable'
 UNION ALL
SELECT *
  FROM (
                SELECT * 
              FROM DailyMeal
             WHERE type = 'fruit'
             LIMIT 1
             ) a
```